# How to track GCS network egress

Tags: google-cloud-storage, google-cloud-platform

We received an email from Google advising us that we will start to be billed for network egress from our Google Cloud Storage bucket (which is our App Engine default bucket). We send several thousand GiB per month, which costs a lot using their [network egress prices](https://cloud.google.com/storage/pricing#network-egress).

We've been working to reduce our egress, but I can't find out how to track our usage. Other than the single email we received telling us about our usage in September, I can't find any reporting or metrics on our GCS usage beyond how much data is stored there. I've looked all throughout the Google Cloud console and Stackdriver console. The closest thing I've found is a page on storing [access logs and storage data](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/access-logs), which I suppose I could start collecting and querying if necessary.

Is there a way I can just see my network egress bandwidth/usage from Google Cloud Storage?

Answer (score 3):

From GCP Billing > Report you can determine total amount of data exported to the GCS bucket. On the filter section you need to set the Time range, Group by = SKU, services= Cloud storage. Please select daily to view the graph properly. Now you can easily find out the Network egress based on the SKU id. To know about Network egress cost based on SKU and Regions, please follow the docs [here](https://cloud.google.com/skus?currency=USD&filter=Egress).

Cloud Storage pricing depends:

1. The amount of data stored in your bucket and also depends on storage class and location
2. If you read/move data from the buckets
3. Total number of operations you performed on the buckets

For more information related to Network egress within google Cloud, please follow the article [here](https://cloud.google.com/storage/pricing#network-buckets).